# What would cause OpenSSL to corrupt a TAR file?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm using openssl to encrypt and decrypt a file, but I'm seeing an odd result.  I would expect the resulting file to be the same as the file I started with, but it is not.  Does anyone know of something that would cause this?  I've already tried a fresh install of openssl with the same result.

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Starting with the initial file (file1) encrypt it

   ```
    # openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -in file1 -out file2 -K 1234abcd -iv 1234
   ```
2. No errors and encrypted file (file2) is created
3. Decrypt the file using the same method

   ```
    # openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in file2 -out file3 -K 1234abcd -iv 1234
   ```
4. Compare the original against the decrypted file (file3)

   ```
    # cksum file1 file3
    4167212980 9021440 file1
    1512110269 9021440 file3

    # cmp file1 file3
    file1 file3 differ: char 1630209, line 6196
   ```

I've run this test on other machines without issue.  There is something odd going on with this one and I'm not sure if it is an openssl issue or something deeper.

This is a cross-compiled version of OpenSSL version 1.0.2r for ARM, but I've seen the same result with 1.0.2n.  The only thing I can think of is to rebuild my file system completely, maybe some underlying library has some cross-compile issue?

**Edit:**
A key piece of evidence that I've noticed.  My file1 was a .tar and so were the original files I was attempting to use OpenSSL for encryption/decryption.  It looks like any tar that I run through OpenSSL results in this issue, but other files are fine.  Simple ascii files, executables, everything I've tried that is not a tarball works fine and passes checks using cksum and cmp.  Any idea how a tar could affect it?

After rebuilding the file system I'm still getting the same result and am puzzled.  This issue doesn't seem to affect any other functions, just this encryption action.

Comment: Hard to believe that this is due to OpenSSL (especially since you also tried a fresh install). Key and IV are too short, but are usually extended to the required length with 0 values (s. [`-p`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html) option). Do common copy processes work in this environment? You might also want to provide details about the OpenSSL version and your environment.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think this is due to OpenSSL it is just a symptom of the actual problem.  The Key and IV are purely for the example and not what I'm using for the actual values.  Common copy works fine without any checksum or diff issues.

Comment: I ended up completely wiping my cross compile build environment and rebuilding everything from scratch.  The new build works as expected without the issue I was experiencing.  I'm not sure if it was something in the underlying compression for the tar, or something else inherently wrong.  But fresh pull of source and a rebuild worked.

Comment: Another piece of info for someone in the future.  I started seeing oddities again and didn't see how it could be the cross compile, openssl, or tar.  I started looking at the physical level and noticed my CPU clock frequency was bad.  I anticipated that I was running 24MHz, but it was significantly lower.